# programmatically removing a drawable Tilemode: android:tileMode="disabled"

Tags: android, android-drawable

I need to programmatically disable the `tilemode` of a drawable that may have it arbitrarily set to `TileMode.CLAMP`, `TileMode.MIRROR` or `TileMode.REPEAT`.

In XML, I can use `android:tileMode="disabled"`, value=-1, to achieve this.

However, programmatically when calling `BitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY` I need to use a `Shader.TileMode` enum member, that has `CLAMP`, `MIRROR` or `REPEAT` but `DISABLED` is absent.

How can I do this?

Comment: That's interessting. What about null? What does it return when you call `BitmapDrawable.getTileModeX` if you disable tile mode in xml?

Comment: hehe was doing this very experiment. NULL works and clears the tileMode !!